# EventKit and App Extensions on the Mac

Tags: macos, cocoa, eventkit

I'm trying to make an App Extension for the Mac that accesses the current users calendars, but it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

I added the Calendar app data capability to the extension (and the main app to see it it would make any difference -- it didn't). I have the following code in my extension:

```
EKEventStore* store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
```

It doesn't even get to the `requestAccessToEntityType:completion:` method (next line) before throwing an error into the console:

```
serviceName = "com.apple.CalendarAgent.database";
} ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134070 "An error occurred in the persistent store." UserInfo=0x61000026dd80 {Problem=request failed, insufficient permission} with userInfo dictionary {

Problem = "request failed, insufficient permission";
```

The documentation says that I can't use APIs "marked in header files with the NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE macro" (no such macros are in the header). It does say "the HealthKit framework and EventKit UI framework are unavailable to app extensions" but EventKit is not "EventKit UI framework" which is iOS only as far as I can tell.

My guess is that there's a problem showing the permissions dialog. Does Apple's Calendar Today Widget have special permissions that third-party apps can't access?

Comment: I raised Radar #19483608 to document this. I'll update if I hear back from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

> > Does Apple's Calendar Today Widget have special permissions that third-party apps can't access?

it is an apple app and doesn't need to worry about permissions AFAIK

---

but:

from reading the docs regarding core location I understand that the extension can only use GPS *after* the user approved it for the app -- I would transfer it to the calendar access! => ergo - in my eyes: it works in the app but not in the ext then it is a **bug**

Comment: Sure, but is there a way that I can do something similar? Am I taking the wrong approach? Am I missing a step? Is it a bug in the OS?

Comment: That was my impression, too. It's always good to get a second opinion! Thank you.